# ошибка при запуске приложения android в android-studio ( Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] )

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

вот код Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button butt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gav);
    butt.setOnClickListener(list);

}

public View.OnClickListener list = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mp.start();
    }

};
}
```

при запуске в Android-studio кидает ошибку `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]`

вот мой манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.root.myapplication3" >
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема решилась изменением конфигурации build.gradle

```
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.root.myapplication3"
    minSdkVersion 19 // изменил на более низкую было 21
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь запустить приложение с минимальным API=15 на устройстве с версией ОС<4.0.3.

Вам надо:

1. Запускать приложение на версии андроид выше 4.0.2

или

2. Понизить требования приложения к версии ОС девайса (см. в манифесте тег  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>` )

Answer (score 2):

Версия API не совпадает с той которая необходима. Если тестируете на телефоне, проверьте его версию Android и ту которую вы указали в приложении.